# Why does the cursor on my Vim appear in pairs when it encounters parentheses?

Tags: highlight

I don't know what to touch. When my cursor moves to the left of the parentheses, the right side of the parentheses is also covered by the cursor.

Is there any way to make my cursor only cover the left side of the parentheses?

What I mean is that when my cursor appears to the left of the parentheses, the right parentheses are also covered by blue squares.

Is there any way to make the right parentheses appear and make the blue square disappear?

[image]

Comment: See [`:h matchparen`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_paren.txt.html?#matchparen)

Comment: You only have one cursor. What is the problem, exactly? That the matching parenthesis is highlighted or that your current colorscheme highlights it in a non-satisfactory way?

Comment: My English is not very good, so there may be some issues with the way I express myself. Because this is my first time asking questions here, I am not very proficient in using this software yet

Comment: Did the answer adressed you question? If so maybe could you validate it using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :--)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following of the hint of @muru you can do:

```
:NoMatchParen
```

If you want to disable it from startup you can add the following line in your `~/.vimrc` file

```
NoMatchParen
```